# Why as.integer() is returning incorrect value?

Tags: r

I am using the following expression in my R-script and getting an incorrect value. I was wondering whether it is a bug or I am doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

> as.integer(10.7275*1e7)

it is returning 107274999. I was expecting it to return 107275000. How can I fix that?

Comment: Are the numbers you are multiplying being generated by a different bit of code? Sometimes it rounds it to fit on the screen, but R holds more accurate information behind the scenes, which could cause this

Comment: `print(10.7275, digits = 18)` gives `>
[1] 10.7274999999999991`. This is because it is not possible for computers to represent numbers precisely. You might want to use `ceiling(10.7275*1e7)`

Comment: simply use ceiling(10.7275*1e7)

Comment: Thanks @RAB. I am not using any code other than R. I get same value even if I enter 10.7275 manually (the actual value is a Latitude -10.7275°, i just use the absolute value of it.).

Comment: Many thanks Suren and Hunaidkhan

Comment: @Nazmul use of `ceiling` might be a work around for a particular case but not for other cases. if you are frequently doing such calculations, you need to increase the accuracy. Using either of `as.double` or `as.numeric`

Comment: I have used round() and got expected result.

Comment: Related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and dealing with floating-point numbers.

Comment: This looks like a floating-point issue. Have a look at some of the answers to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1364007) for some suggestions on why this happens and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to computer inaccuracy with decimals (as mentioned in comments by @Suren). You can get around it by:

```
as.integer(ceiling(10.7275*1e7))
```

## Note:

```
ceiling(as.integer(10.7275*1e7))
```

will not work (it will return the value you are getting now).

Answer (score -1):

Its a floating point issue. One quick fix would be to use double precision floating point for better accuracy:

```
as.double(10.7275*1e7)                       # alternatively as.numeric()

# [1] 107275000
```

Also refer to this [floating point post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) to get more information and resolutions for floating point math as commented by @Wai Ha Lee